# Run a scheduled job against 440+ sql server instances from a single server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

sorry, I haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking to accomplish in the message title so, here I am with maybe a duplicate question...

So... I have 440+ sql server instances registered in my local SSMS instance and what I want to do is to schedule a very simple T-SQL statement to run against all of those registered servers on a nightly basis.  I don't want to mess around with 440+ sql server agent instances if I can avoid it for obvious reasons(I think).  Any advice?

Comment: you can look at "Redgate SQL Multi Script" tool

Comment: Sounds like a job for PowerShell (or tools like Redgate's), not SQL Server Agent.

Comment: So you are managing 440 SQL Server instances? Sounds like you need a proper management tool for that, it's way beyond SSMS

Comment: Thanks all, I agree that I don't want to introduce 440+ additional points of failure using SQL Server Agent.  I've used some of Redgate's tools in the past so I'll head back there.

Comment: I certainly might be missing something, but it doesn't appear that the Redgate Multisript tool can be run against instances registered in Local Server Groups - am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like you might have to do that manually once (but it may be easy enough to reverse engineer how the tool stores a manual selection and build that list in a more automated way). https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/84624/feature-request-import-database-distribution-list-from-a-database

Comment: ...I think the list of server names is the easy part, the harder part is going to be credentials. But you'd have a similar issue with anything - 440 linked servers would need to have security set up too.